# Programmatically configuration of the ResourceBundleMessageSource

Tags: spring-mvc

I am trying to configure `Spring MVC` programmatically instead of xml files. Almost everything is working fine, but I am having troubles with the `ResourceBundleMessageSource` declaration.

My configuration class looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "xx.xx.xx.spring.controller")

public class MvcConfig {

    @Bean
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource configureResourceBundleMessageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource resource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        resource.setBasename("messages");
        return resource;
    }

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver configureUrlBasedViewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(
            org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

And my initializer like this:

```
public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) 
            throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext mvcContext = 
            new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        mvcContext.register(MvcConfig.class);
        mvcContext.setServletContext(servletContext);
        mvcContext.refresh();
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic menu = servletContext.addServlet("menu", 
            new DispatcherServlet(mvcContext));
        menu.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        menu.addMapping("*.html");
    }
}
```

The application is working, but it is not showing the messages from `messages.properties` that is located in `/WEB-INF/classes/messages.properties`. And if I use xml files it works fine too.

In the JSP I have the following line±

```
<fmt:message key="heading"/>
```

And it is displayed like `???heading???` in the browser.

I dont know if it is a problem with the path or I need to put more params.

Comment: try resource.setBasename("classpath:messages");

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work. I am a bit frustrated...

Comment: then i suggest you place a break point in ResourceBundleMessageSource  to see where it tries to find the file.

Comment: Ok. The code even runs. If I configure it with the XML the execution stops in the breakpoint, but if I use the programmatically configuration, it doesnt. I will keep investigating but I am going to keep the XML just with the bundle configuration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

and finally It's working! The problem was in the method name. If you want to create a bean with a id, the id of the bean is the name of the method. So i have changed the name of the method (`configureResourceBundleMessageSource()`) to `messageSource()`.

Comment: Or you can specify bean name in annotation: `@Bean(name = "messageSource")`